# Not able to automate button click on "Oracle VM virtual box" using pywinauto in python

Tags: python, automation, virtual-machine, pywinauto

I am working on the Automation of loading an image file in "Oracle VM Virtual box" to create a virtual machine using Pywinauto in python. I am able to automate the installation of Virtual Box software & after that able to launch the exe also shown in the image

[image: VM Tool GUI]

But after that I am not able to do any GUI operation on "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager" (e.g.Selecting File Menu or click New button) automatically using Pywinauto. I have attached the snapshot of Inspect tool for Oracle VM Virtual box

[image: Inspect Tool VM VirtualBox]

Below is the code which I am trying to run

```
>>> from pywinauto import application
>>> app=application.Application()

>>> app.start(r"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe")
<pywinauto.application.Application object at 0x000001D671679BA8>

>>>app['Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager']['New']
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x000001D670FB9CC0>

>>> app['Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager']['New'].click()
```

After executing click command shown above I am getting error

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 246, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 453, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    app['Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager']['New'].click()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 352, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 249, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 431, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 210, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'New', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <win32_element_info.HwndElementInfo - 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager', Qt5QWindowIcon, 68992>, 'backend': 'win32'}
```

In Inspect tool it is showing that Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager window "Is Keyboard focusable" is false & there is no Automation ID for these controls.

Please suggest me the commands to perform buttons click automation on this GUI. I am new to python & not able to understand what should I do next.

Comment: Please format the question so it can be easily readable your code

Comment: Hi Gourav, I am new to SO, do not know exactly how to format the question. I tried my best to represent the code readable

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Inspect.exe`, you must use `Application(backend="uia")` as an entry point. This is described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Default backend is "win32", so it can be used if `Spy++` can see this button (I suppose the answer is "no").

Comment: Thanks @Vasily Ryabov for the valuable guidance.


After using Application(backend="uia") I was able to Click on the buttons but still I am not able to access the **Menu Items**. 
e.g. help-> aboutvirtualbox

I used below command to access the menu items
**app.OracleVMVirtualBoxManager.MenuSelect("help->aboutvirtualbox")**

Please suggest if I am not using proper command

Comment: First off `CamelCase` method names are not used for "uia" backend, use `menu_select` instead. Also some menus are not covered by this method due to non-standard structure. If it's Qt5 app, you can use [examples/wireshark.py, Line 58+](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/wireshark.py#L58) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks @Vasily Ryabov. 
I have read in your other posts that **CamelCase** are not used, So I am always try to avoid CamelCase method names but in my first notepad python program **menu_select** was not working properly so I am using **MenuSelect** method
I will use your given solution & try to fully automate my task & will get back

Comment: `MenuSelect` is a direct alias for `menu_select` in "win32" backend: `MenuSelect = menu_select` in the code. Also `MenuSelect` doesn't exist for "uia" backend.