# windows specification class has no click method

Tags: button, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto to automate a windows GUI. app.machine.Reset.click() returns the following error

```
  File "C:\PythonCAT\x64\2.6\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 236, in __getattr__
    return getattr(ctrls[-1], attr)
AttributeError: 'ButtonWrapper' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I have tried using `click_input()` & `click()`. I get the same error message `AttributeError: 'ButtonWrapper' object has no attribute 'click'`.
I read documentation related to pywinauto as well

The solution in the post below did not work for me. I am using python 2.6.6 and pywinauto version 0.5.0

[Not able to automate button click on "Oracle VM virtual box" using pywinauto in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866951/not-able-to-automate-button-click-on-oracle-vm-virtual-box-using-pywinauto-in)

```
from pywinauto.application import Application


def test():
    try:
         os.startfile(r'''machine.exe''')
         app= Application().connect(path=r'''machine.exe''')
         app.machine.DrawOutline()
         app.machine.PrintControlIdentifiers()
         #app.machine.menu_select("File->Exit")
         app.machine.Reset.click()
         #app.machine.Reset.click_input()
     finally:
         print(" done")
test()
```

`app.machine.Reset.click()` returns the following error:

```
  File "C:\PythonCAT\x64\2.6\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 236, in __getattr__
    return getattr(ctrls[-1], attr)
AttributeError: 'ButtonWrapper' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Any help is appreciated. All the posts I have read recommend using click() or invoke() or click_input(). I have tried using each of them and I got the same error message for each. I am trying to click on the button Reset in the GUI.

Comment: This happens because the button wasn't really found. Use `.dump_tree()` from top level window specification to see proper search attributes of child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.machine.Button9.Click() worked for me.

app.machine.PrintControlIdentifiers() gave me the list of identifiers for the controls present on the GUI. One of them is Button9.So instead of using the name of the button called Reset using Button9 worked fine.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted. It's OK. Just click on gray check box at the left side of the answer.